# Viewing Direction as 3D Cartesian Unit Vector

Tags: geometry, transformation, spherical-coordinates

I am reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.08934.pdf), where they represent a "2D viewing direction ($\theta$, $\phi$) as a 3D Cartesian unit vector **d**". Unfortunately, no further explanation is given and I am not familiar with this concept. My first intention was that they applied a rotation matrix on the standard Cartesian unit vectors, but I don't see how this fits in three dimensions. Can anyone elaborate on that please or link me to a useful source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that $(\theta, \phi)$ represent spherical coordinates. The third spherical coordinate, $r$ can be assumed to be $1$, since we’re dealing with a unit vector. Unfortunately, there are (at least) two conventions for spherical coordinates, so it’s hard to say exactly what $\theta$ and $\phi$ mean. More [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

Comment: Ahh yes I think you are right. They probably simply set r to 1 and then make a coordinate transformation from spherical to cartesian through the well known transformations x = cos($\phi$)sin($\theta$), y = sin($\phi$)sin($\theta$), z = cos($\theta$). This gives a 3d cartesian vector with unit length.

Comment: Yes, but some people interchange the meanings of the two angles, as the Wikipedia page explains. But, one way or the other, this is probably their intention.

Answer (score 1):

The direction is specified using two angles, so I'd read that as a direction in space. A 3d coordinate vector of unit length makes sense for that, as does a spherical coordinate system using two angles. The fact that the paper speaks about "2d" in my opinion does not reflect that this is a direction in a plane, but instead that the direction is essentially equivalent to a point on a (unit) sphere. That sphere itself is a two-dimensional surface, albeit a curved one not a flat plane.